# Tar compress Zenity progress

Tags: bash, tar, zenity

I wish to show the progress with zenity of a Tar compression of a folder.

Consider the following code to compress the Document folder to bzip2.

```
(tar -cf - Documents | pv -n -s $(du -sb Documents | awk '{print $1}') \ 
| bzip2 > test.tar.bz2) | zenity --progress --percentage=0
```

The progress is displayed in the terminal using pv by displaying the percentage line by line.

```
3
9
16
27
...
```

However, zenity does not display the progress and remains locked at 0%. When the process is complete, zenity displays 100%.
How to fix my mistake and to view progression in zenity? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pv` reports the progress on `stderr`, `zenity` reads from `stdin`, so it never sees what `pv` reports. When `stdin` is closed it switches to 100%.

Try this, that should fix it:

```
(tar -cf - Documents | pv -n -s $(du -sb Documents | awk '{print $1}') \ 
| bzip2 > test.tar.bz2) 2>&1 | zenity --progress --percentage=0
```

Comment: Works fine ! Thanks.